# resulted vs. resulting

Tags: word-difference

Consider these sentences:

> The next stage is to identify the defects in the image **resulting** from the previous stage.
>
> The next stage is to identify the defects in the image **resulted** from the previous stage.

Which is correct or common? why?

Comment: The second sentence would never be composed by a native English speaker. It is meaningless unless _that_ or _which_ is inserted before _resulted._ Please tell us why you think you could use _resulted_ here?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - to a non native the difference is less obvious, maybe you can explaind why it sounds "wrong" to you.

Comment: @xxxxxx Ahmad's  answer to the question _"Why do you think you could use resulted here?"_ will help us to understand his thinking and correct his error.

Comment: @P.E.Dant as xxxxxx suggested, I have no idea, you may explain why the second sentence would never be used by a native speaker!! and what is that wrong with it!

Comment: @P.E.Dant OK!, *image resulted from* to me is like any other reduced relative clause! where *which is resulted* is reduced to "resulted"

Comment: @P.E.Dant now I even get interested in knowing why a *which* can make the second sentence acceptable!

Comment: @Ahmad If you really have no idea why _resulted_ could be substituted for _resulting_ in this sentence, why did you suggest it? (Also, _"which is resulted_" is nonsensical in English. That phrase can never appear in a correct English sentence.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant As I said, "*which is resulted*" is like any other relative clause to me, for example like "*which is derived*", why you say "which is derived" and reduce it to "derived" but you don't do that for "resulted". Anyway its a question you should answer why?! By the way, I hear and read some patterns here and there but don't know the underlying structure.

Comment: @Ahmad "result" is an intransitive verb, we often (particularly I) forget to check some ostensible "easy" words in the dictionary, leading to such discussions.

Comment: @cardinal thanks. Interesting point ! Then you mean "X results Y" or "X results in Y" and "Y reaults from X" but not "Y is resulted from X'. Its like "شکست" in Persian, however we say both "شکست" and "شکسته شد". Mother language interference has a role here.

Comment: @Ahmad You're welcome; I didn't notice that at the first time myself. Yes, mother language interference plays a key role here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I noticed my mistake and answered my question. Now I see, why you didn't expect a verb like "is resulted" because it doesn't exit!

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the second sentence is that "which is resulted" cannot be reduced to "resulted", because "**result**" is an intransitive verb (which takes no object.)

We have :

> X causes Y.
>
> Y results from X.

That is a common mistake for learners like me, whose mother language has a single transitive verb for both of the verbs above. We may confuse it with the pattern for any transitive verb like "push:"

> X pushes Y.
>
> Y is pushed by X.

However, there is a phrasal verb "result in" which is almost similar to "cause:"

> X results in Y
>
> Y results from X

Comment: Well done. I refrained from answering you in commentary because I hoped that you would think more deeply about the question, which is a very simple one!